# Чтение xls с удаленного сервера через PHPExel

Tags: php, phpexcel

есть вот такой код:

```
     $file_path_excel = "http://site.ua/system/PHPExcel/my.xls";
function readExelFile($filepath){
    require_once "Classes/PHPExcel.php"; //подключаем наш фреймворк
    $ar=array(); // инициализируем массив
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($filepath);  // узнаем тип файла, excel может хранить файлы в разных форматах, xls, xlsx и другие
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType); // создаем объект для чтения файла
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filepath); // загружаем данные файла в объект
$ar = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(); // выгружаем данные из объекта в массив
return $ar; //возвращаем массив
}

$ar=readExelFile($file_path_excel);
foreach($ar as $ar_colls){

делаем что то....
```

По пути который я вставляю файл скачивается , если перейти через браузер.
а phpexel открыть его не может.

код ошибки

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message 'Could not open http://.....ua/system/PHPExcel/my.xls for reading! File does not exist.' in ....www/system/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel5.php:433
```

Подскажите, как мне получить файл с удаленного сервера?

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Подскажите, как мне получить файл с удаленного сервера?

Попробуйте так

```
$filecontent = file_get_contents("http://site.ua/system/PHPExcel/my.xls");
if (!$filecontent){
    throw new Exception("Can't read remote file");
}
file_put_contents(PATH_TMP."/my.xls", $filecontent);

$ar=readExelFile(PATH_TMP."/my.xls");
...
```

Comment: Как раз сейчас читаю документацию по этим функциям. спасибо. сейчас попробую

Comment: Ну так для разнообразия 
`if(copy("http://site.ua/system/PHPExcel/my.xls",PATH_TMP."/my.xls")) { readExcelFile()}` а у вас ошибка ибо даже если не будет файла `readExcelFile` всё равно его будет читать.

Comment: @Naumov , не в обработке ошибок был смысл поста. Отредактировал.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр я не про обработку ошибок сделал замечание а про то что у вас ошибка в алгоритме была. Ну и велосипед `file_get_contents` и `file_put_contents`. эти же действия выполняет одна команда `copy`. Плюсом если `file_get_contents` запрашивать недоступный фаил или сервер, вы получите ошибку `bad getway`. По этому лучше добавить определённы timeout запроса в контексте.

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = basename($file_path_excel);

$content = file_get_contents($file_path_excel);
if (file_put_contents($filename, $content)) {
    readExelFile($filename);
    unlink($filename);
} else
    die("Something went wrong");
```

Вы должны сначало сохранить файл в своей системе локально, потом его открывать.